# Python list.append dictionaries with same pattern in a loop. The Dictionary is updated per loop, while the list is update in a whole

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append

There is a pattern in a text file and I use regex to extra them all in to tuples.
"a host (e.g., '146.204.224.152')
a user_name (e.g., 'feest6811' note: sometimes the user name is missing! In this case, use '-' as the value for the username.)
the time a request was made (e.g., '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700')
the post request type (e.g., 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1' note: not everything is a POST!)"

I'm using for loop to iterate tuples, create a corresponding dictionary and append it to a list.

The result is quite strange since the dictionary is created/update without problems in the loop, while the list will only be full of the last iterated content of dictionary(i.e., previous appended items will be overlapped by the last appended dictionary?). May I know the reason?

```
example_dict = {"host":"146.204.224.152", 
                "user_name":"feest6811", 
                "time":"21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700",
                "request":"POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1"}


def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
    tp = re.findall(r'([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\s-\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[\-])\s\[(.*)\]\s\"(.*)\"',logdata)
    ls = list()
    dt = dict()
    for itp in tp:
        dt['host'] = itp[0]
        dt['user_name'] = itp[1]
        dt['time'] = itp[2]
        dt['request'] = itp[3]
        ls.append(dt)
    return(ls)
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

The result looks like:

iteration 1:

```
dict----- {'host': '146.204.224.152',
           'user_name': 'feest6811', 
           'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 
           'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}

list-----  [{'host': '146.204.224.152', 
            'user_name': 'feest6811', 
            'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700', 
            'request': 'POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1'}]
```

iteration 2:

```
dict----- {'host': '197.109.77.178', 
           'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 
           'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', 
           'request': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0'}

list----- [{'host': '197.109.77.178', 
            'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 
            'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', 
            'request': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0'}, 
           {'host': '197.109.77.178', 
            'user_name': 'kertzmann3129', 
            'time': '21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700', 
            'request': 'DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0'}]
... ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you define your dictionary *outside* of the loop. You update the *same* dictionary with every iteration of the loop and append the *same* dictionary to the list. I'd expect the list to have identical values for each element in it.

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```py
def logs():
    with open("assets/logdata.txt", "r") as file:
        logdata = file.read()
    tp = re.findall(r'([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\s-\s([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[\-])\s\[(.*)\]\s\"(.*)\"',logdata)

    # The list will be instantiated outside of the loop
    ls = []

    for itp in tp:
        # We create a NEW dictionary in each loop and append it to the list
        ls.append({
            "host": itp[0],
            "user_name": itp[1],
            "time": itp[2],
            "request": itp[3],
        })

    return(ls)
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. However, every time I tried to print out the dt as a whole after several assignment(overlap the old values with same keys)in my old loop, say, add print(dt) between dt['request'] = itp[3] and  ls.append(dt), the content actually changed. How can I explain this?

Comment: By printing intermediate results you see what the dictionary looked like at that **point in time**, which was correct. But you immediately overwrote the content of that dictionary in the next iteration of the loop. The mistake was that you seemed to assume you were creating a copy of the dictionary whereas you actually modified the original each time.